# Arm scatter file issue

Tags: c, arm, embedded

So I'm relatively new with arm and I'm having problems with scatter files. This next file is what I have in the project I entered:

```
ROOT  0x00020200 0x000DFDFC
{
    ITCM 0x00020200
    {
       ssw01fiq.o (Startup, +First)
       startup.o (+RO)
       ssw01irq.o (+RO)
    }

    EXEC_REST +0
    {
       * (+RO)
    }
    
    DTCM 0x00400000 {startup.o (StartOfRAM, +First)}

    SCT  +0x348
    {
       ibmp_slot.o* (+ZI);
    }
    
    INIT_CALL +0
    {
        * (INIT)
    }

    SRAM +0
    {
        * (+RW, +ZI)
        startup.o* (DummyStack, +Last)
    }

    JUSTAFTERRAM 0x00410000
    {
        startup.o* (JustAfterRAM)
    }
    JUSTAFTERROM 0x00100000
    {
        startup.o* (JustAfterROM)
    }
}
```

So, what I would like to do is add a new execution region called INIT_CALL and then, on the source code, I will define pointers to init functions and place them at the INIT section (in a simple way this is what is done on the linux kernel...).
For that I use a macro like this:

```
typedef int (*_init_fn) (void);
#define component_init(__fn)   static _init_fn  fn __attribute__((section ("INIT"))) = __fn
```

And in one .c file im using it to initialize some init funtion.

```
component_init(productUiInitialize);
void dump_fn()
{
   printf("Here we have, fn=0x%08X, addr=0x%08X\n", fn, &fn);
}
```

On the other .c file i do this:

```
extern int productUiInitialize(void);
_init_fn *test = (_init_fn *)0x00400F78;
void do_init_calls( void )
{
   dump_fn();
   printf("FUNC=0x%08X, INITCALL=0x%08X, ADDR=0x%08X\n",productUiInitialize, *test, test);
}
```

So, the outcome is really strange, I see that my pointers are not being well initialized, they have NULL value. I then noticed, if I use const in my define the pointer in the dump_fn function will be ok, so the addr is `0x00400F78` and value is the addr of `productUiInitialize`. But on the  other `c` file, the value of test is naturally `0x00400F78`, but when I dereference it I have `NULL` (I was expecting to have `productUiInitialize`).
Am I doing anything wrong at the scatter file?? Some inputs would be really appreciated...

**UPDATE**: So i recently had some more time to look into this. What i found is that, if i set my INIT section inside SRAM everything works as expected. The problem is, in this case i don't know how to force the init address and the size of my SECTION. Moreover i checked that if i initialized a variable like this in test.c :

_init_fn  *fn **attribute**((section ("INIT"))) = (init *)0x00400F78;

The variable is not correctly initialized. When i print it's value is something else completely different of 0x00400F78. So it seems that if my section is outside the SRAM execution region (where RW and ZI section are) things don't work as i expected. So i have basically two questions, Does anyone knows why of this behavior? Also, is there any possibility of forcing an init address for my section INIT, if i place it inside SRAM execution region?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *But on the other c file, the value of test is naturally 0x00400F78, but when i dereference it i have NULL* - I have no idea of what this means.

Comment: Test is pointer to _init_fn, so basically is a pointer to a pointer of a function. So in the printf statement test is printed with 0x00400F78, but *test (dereferencing my pointer) is NULL and it should be the address of  productUiInitialize (or at least i was expecting that).

Comment: Isn't the `0x00400F78` an address of the function, not the address of the address of the function? And FYI, if `fn` is a function, both `fn` and `&fn` have the same value.

Comment: No. 0x00400F78 is the address of fn, so &fn is 0x00400F78. Now the value of fn is the address of the function productUiInitialize...